A tool or any way to fast way convert html to image that can integrate in c#
I want to convert html pages to lightweight image (or byte) to print. I require a high conversion speed. I have tried some solutions:

wkhtmltopdf and some wrapper: around 1s, but the newest version of wkhtmltopdf does not support flex
puppeteerSharp: around 1s, but I' think it is not the right way and I think there maybe other lightweight headless browsers that can handle this case faster.

First time working with printer, hope someone share me the way you used to handle this, or any performance way to handle in other language (py/c++)
